# The right approach to keep users sessions

Tags: ios, objective-c

I’m developing an app that uses external API and requires authentication through oauth2. In the response from api I get access token, refresh token and time in which token will expire. Everything is just fine until the time expire. So far before sending a request i check whether access token is valid:

```
if ([[AppCredentials sharedCredentials]tokenIsValid]) {
    BackEnd *backendPUT = [[BackEnd alloc]init];
    [backendPUT setDelegate:self];
    [backendPUT updateMenuInDiary:menuDietyDoUpdate forDate:[[DziennikDietaModel sharedDziennikDietaModel]getwybranaDate] mealID:[menuDietyDoUpdate objectForKey:@"id"]];
    monitor = [[UICustomLoadingMonitor alloc]initWithDefaultOptionsInView:[self view]];
    [monitor start];
}else{
    [[AppCredentials sharedCredentials] getAppTokenFromRefreshedToken];
}
```

when getAppTokenFromRefreshedToken is finished, method userTokenDownloaded is called using delegate.
The question is: how can I go back to that certain code which could not be executed in the first part of the if statement? Everything is asynchronous that is why i’ve got a problem.

In my view controller there are couple of methods that sends different requests to api and I need to differentiate which one needs to be called again.

What would be the right approach to this? closures ?

Comment: When you get the new token, why not just call this same method again?

Comment: in that case I would need as many delegate methods as api requests in my view controller instead of just single getAppTokenFromRefreshedToken * number of view controller as each requests something different

Comment: OK...I was taking "there are couple of methods" literally.  :)

Comment: I'll express myself better next time, thanks for the answer though :)

Answer (score 0):

ok. solved it with blocks :) in the case someone was looking for an answer that is how i've done it:

```
 BackEnd *backEnd = [[BackEnd alloc]init];
 [backEnd setDelegate:self];
 if ([[AppCredentials sharedCredentials]tokenIsValid]) {
         NSLog(@"TOKEN VALID NO BLOCKS");
         [backEnd updateMenuInDiary:menuDietyDoUpdate];
 }else{
        NSLog(@"USING BLOCKS");
        [backEnd getAppTokenFromRefreshToken:refreshedToken withCompletionBlock:^{
            NSLog(@"ponowna proba z bloku");
            [backEnd updateMenuInDiary:menuDietyDoUpdate];
       }];
}
```

works great :)

Comment: Nice, good solution. Personally i really like PromiseKit (http://promisekit.org) makes your code look clean & mean ;)

Comment: thanks :) and thanks for the link, it looks very promising